# Media Query to target tablets and mobiles

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-mobile

We are developing a Web application.
The main scope is to target different tablets resolution and browsers. 
A few are Android 5, 7 and 10 inch and iPhone 5, 7 and 10 inch. 
We are using jQuery Mobile and MVC to target different browser, but to target different resolution we found media query would be helpful to adjust font size,div width etc..

**What media query width should I specify?**

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px)
{
}
```

The min-width and max width to target android 5, 7 and 10 inch and iphone 5,7,10 ?

I saw different stack overflow question but not satisfied with answer they given.

Comment: JQM is responsive to any resolution. Just make sure to add viewport meta tag.

Comment: Are you wanting it so that the application is responsive - so that if you put the browser window the same size as a phone - they'd have the same look and feel?

Comment: @Omar ya JQM looks great. but how to define font size for labels? label with font size in % looks good in 10 inch tablet but becoming 2 lines in 7 inch tablet.

Comment: @wildandjam:yes.. but now we supporting only tablet

Comment: I only ask because max-width will give you that, whereas max-device-width will give a different experience. So stick with max-width. There is something about pixel density, let me try and get a link for you.... http://cssmediaqueries.com/target/

Comment: @wildandjam thanqs lot. Is max-width or min-width supported in ipad mini?

Comment: Yes both are supported. This will get the ipad mini (and ipad 1 + 2): @media screen and (device-width: 768px) and (device-height: 1024px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 1)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55961/discussion-between-ryder-and-wildandjam).

Answer (score 2):

This is a guide from [CSS tricks](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/) - Hope this helps

/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
    @media only screen 
    and (min-device-width : 320px) 
    and (max-device-width : 480px) {
    /* Styles */
    }

```
/* Smartphones (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 321px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (max-width : 320px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : landscape) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : portrait) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Desktops and laptops ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 1224px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Large screens ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 1824px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPhone 4 ----------- */
@media
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5),
only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5) {
/* Styles */
}
```